# Запуск Java-программы без javac (JDK 11)

Tags: java, javac

Имеется:

`JDK 11` и примитивная программа:

```
public class HelloWorld {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }

}
```

и применённая к ней команда `chmod +x HelloWorld`

Необходимо: запустить программу командой `./HelloWorld` для печати в терминале:

```
Hello, World
```

минуя `javac`

Comment: На будущее: под формой написания вопроса есть галочка "Ответить на собственный вопрос", позволяющая одновременно с вопросом опубликовать и ответ.

Comment: @D-side я пока еще так не научился(( Может в следующий раз попробую

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Решение.**

Шаг 1: Создаём файл `nano HelloWorld`

Шаг 2:

```
#! /usr/local/java/jdk-11-ea18/bin/java --source 11

public class HelloWorld {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }

}
```

Шаг 3: ctrl+o, ctrl+x

Шаг 4: `chmod +x HelloWorld`

Шаг 5: `./HelloWorld`

Видим, что программа отработала, и напечатала

> Hello, World